# Calculating rolling sum in a pandas dataframe on the basis of 2 variable constraints

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a variable : **SumOfPrevious5OccurencesAtIDLevel** which is the sum of previous 5 values (as per Date variable) of ***Var1*** at an ID level (column 1) , otherwise it will take a value of NA

Sample Data and Output:

```
ID  Date      Var1  SumOfPrevious5OccurencesAtIDLevel
1   1/1/2018    0   NA
1   1/2/2018    1   NA
1   1/3/2018    2   NA
1   1/4/2018    3   NA
2   1/1/2018    4   NA
2   1/2/2018    5   NA
2   1/3/2018    6   NA
2   1/4/2018    7   NA
2   1/5/2018    8   NA
2   1/6/2018    9   30
2   1/7/2018    10  35
2   1/8/2018    11  40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and functions [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
#if not sorted ID with datetimes
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])

df['new'] = df.groupby('ID')['Var1'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(5).sum().shift())
print (df)
    ID       Date  Var1  SumOfPrevious5OccurencesAtIDLevel   new
0    1 2018-01-01     0                                NaN   NaN
1    1 2018-01-02     1                                NaN   NaN
2    1 2018-01-03     2                                NaN   NaN
3    1 2018-01-04     3                                NaN   NaN
4    2 2018-01-01     4                                NaN   NaN
5    2 2018-01-02     5                                NaN   NaN
6    2 2018-01-03     6                                NaN   NaN
7    2 2018-01-04     7                                NaN   NaN
8    2 2018-01-05     8                                NaN   NaN
9    2 2018-01-06     9                               30.0  30.0
10   2 2018-01-07    10                               35.0  35.0
11   2 2018-01-08    11                               40.0  40.0
```

Comment: If data is not sorted by ID and Date , then  ? df['new'] = df.sort_values(['ID','Date']).groupby('ID')['Var1'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(5).sum().shift())

Comment: @user3643528 - Good point, then need convert column to datetime and  sorting like in edited answer.